# Why does tar with -z option create archive with different hash everytime

Tags: linux, gzip, md5, tar, md5sum

Can you tell me why

```
tar czf archive.tar dir
```

creates archive with different hash everytime (I check with 'md5sum')
Without compression parameter -z or with parameter -j instead all works fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because `gzip` stores meta-information too when using default parameters. Take a look at the `-n` parameter of `gzip` to discard that information, then you should have identical archives every time, assuming the files did not change.

Try something like: `tar -cf <archive_dir> | gzip -n > archive_dir.tar.gz`

Take a look at the [gzip manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?gzip).